# Continuous forms, many fields, and ease of data entry in MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2010

I will be creating a MS Access form based on a hard copy.  The hard copy has a column of labels and then 3 columns of fill-in-the-blank.

The problem is that there are 30 categories which means 90 fields if it were to be a continuous form.  If it is not a continuous form then the categories must be selected one by one from the drop down.

Is there a way to set the categories static - possibly give each a different code - but have just the 3 fields in the table rather than having 90 fields?

Or perhaps, can the drop down be a permanent list?

Comment: What is the 'column of labels'? Is that for category 1 thru 30, and then you enter three pieces of information for each line item (category?). If yes, and yes, then there are ways in which your form can avoid defining 90 fields. i.e. pre-load a 'transaction' table with 30 rows for the 30 categories (and the other three fields are empty).

Comment: Exactly.  Thank you for the interpretation as I may not have explained it very well.  Pre-load a transaction table sounds like what I need to do but uncertain how the categories go into the form once data entry starts.

Comment: The 'hard copy' must be based on something. .. a month or site or ??? So create a table just for categories, load the 30 into that table. Then populate a transaction table with the 30 categories and perform the data entry. Your form is continuous and will have the 30 rows.